# Only odd columns in arrayformula on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple columns that I need to stack into one column. But I only want to have odd columns in the list.

This is the formula I'm working with, which works to get all in one column. But not just odd ones
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A:D,A:A>0)&"*"))),"*"))

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yAPw13VE7uclP0ILzUYxZBgLGid9PrZXpWmhuEgi1S0/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

`=QUERY(FLATTEN(FILTER(A:D,ISODD(COLUMN(A:D)))),"Select * Where Col1 Is Not Null")`

`FILTER` filters in all cells from odd columns.

`FLATTEN` makes one column of all of the `FILTER`ed results.

`QUERY` weeds out blank rows.

Comment: I started to answer this but my answer would have been identical to yours except for transpose to get the two columns into row order =QUERY(FLATTEN(transpose(FILTER(A:D,ISODD(COLUMN(A:D))))),"Select * Where Col1 Is Not Null")

Answer (score 2):

You can also use QUERY with 'skipping 2' option. This takes only every 2nd row so to make it useful you have to transpose your range first. Then you FLATTEN your columns.
As you can see, there's a different order of values:

```
=flatten(query(transpose(A1:D4),"select * skipping 2 "))
```

[image]